# How do I get the percentage of a colour in a screen in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I am new to pygame and trying to create a 'splatoon' like game, I got the basic elements ready but I don't know how to calculate the percentage of the screen. Do I individually scan each pixel using get_at or is there an easier method to calculate it?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
silver = (192, 192, 192)
aqua = (0, 255,255)
x = 10
y =490
a = 490
b = 10
vel = 1
pygame.init()
FPS = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
while True:
    seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if seconds <= 10:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        color = black
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 490:
            x += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and a < 490:
            a += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 0:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and a > 0:
            a -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > 0:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and b > 0:
            b -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 490:
            y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and b < 490:
            b += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_e]:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, aqua, (x-20,y-20,50,50))
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, silver, (a-20,b-20,50,50))
        if keys[pygame.K_p]:
            win.fill((0,0,0))

        pygame.draw.rect(win, aqua, (x,y,10,10))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, silver, (a,b,10,10))
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Do you mean the percentage of the screen that is covered with a specific color?

Comment: Yes, it will then determine which color wins.

Comment: You're kind of confusing visual and logic. The logic of your code should determine the visual, not the other way round. That means: keep track of which parts of the screen get which color, and then computing the percentage is not only easy, but much cleaner (as in: more maintainable code)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a function like this, using `pygame.Surface.get_at()`:

```py
def get_percentage(color, step=1):

    width, height = screen_size
    total_number_of_pixels = width * height
    number_of_pixels = 0

    for x in range(0, width, step):
        for y in range(0, height, step):
            if screen.get_at((x, y)) == color:
                number_of_pixels += 1

    percentage = number_of_pixels / total_number_of_pixels * 00
    return percentage
```

But because it can considerably slow down the code, you may store the percentage and call this function only when the percentage is updated (for example if a player attacks).

And you can change the `step` var in the code above to get the percentage more roughly (and quicker).